# How to install php_wincache extension for php 7.1 on Windows?

Tags: php, wincache

I've followed all instructions from this tutorial
[wincache installition](http://php.net/manual/en/wincache.installation.php)

but at the end I've got an error:

```
Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\dev\7.1\php\ext\php_wincache.dll'
```

What can be the problem? php_wincache.dll exists in the needed folder, but can'be be found by php.

Comment: I do not know either. I would like to know if in 2020 wincache is still beneficial. The latest release 2.0.0.8 was [released on pecl.php.net on 2016-11-09](http://pecl.php.net/package/WinCache). For php 7.4  [wincache 2.0.0.8 was released 2020-01](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wincache/) on sourceforge. The  [Wincache on github](https://github.com/php/pecl-caching-wincache/graphs/contributors) has no commits since 2015-08.